# External HDD - Unique Identifier

Tags: powershell-2.0

I'm writing a PowerShell script to notify the user each morning that he needs to change the External HDD that's connected to his computer. When he already changed the disk, the user don't get notified.

In order to do this, I want to check a unique identifier of the current disk to a unique identifier of the disk of the previous day. The only downside is that I don't find a unique string that I can use? Does anybody have an idea?

The script needs to run on PowerShell 2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set a unique volume label for each disk and retrieve that - see [Change Drive Letters and Labels via a Simple PowerShell Command](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/03/14/change-drive-letters-and-labels-via-a-simple-powershell-command.aspx)

Comment: Do you know if getHashCode (of Get-PSDrive) is influenced by the content on the drive?

Comment: Working with labels fixed my 'problem'. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Jente glad it helped. as for getHashCode - I do not know for shore but I would think it very likely that it uses some sort of hardware id instead of crunching changing bits